# Do villager mechanics apply vertically?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, to avoid villagers getting confused with breeding mechanics, etc., any group of villagers (i.e. Iron Farm, Villager Spawner etc.) need to be placed >64 blocks away.

Does this apply vertically, or is it to do with Chunk mechanics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distance of 64 is required between doors of different villages, not the villager entities. The distance is spherical, so it applies vertically as well - see the old DocM77 iron farm tutorial for example: